# Access api data in child component on ready with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, api, components, vue.js

I've working on a big application and I'm having a lot of trouble dealing with data from my API and passing it onto my child components.

**The situation.**

I'm calling my API from the parent component and passing the data through a prop to my child component. The child component displays the data just fine, but I'm not able to access the data within the ready function in my child component.

Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/kmrfkynf/3/

As you can see in the console, displaying the data within the child components ready function gives me a empty object...

```
ready: function(){
    console.log('items from child component', this.items);
}
```

... but the child components renders the object just fine within my repeat.

So the problem is that the child component is rendered before the API call from the parent is complete. When its complete, it syncs the data to my child component, thus rendering just fine.

**What I've tried**

Watching the prop from within my child component. When the prop is 'complete' I can access it. But this gives me lots of problems when trying to modify some data in the prop, because it renders every time. This is not the solution I want.

**The question**

How can I make sure that the prop is filled when the child component is ready?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Right now i'm using events to broadcast when my data is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the DOM is loaded and ready while the AJAX function is still receiving the data.  So the ready method on the component fires before the results come back from the server.

You could fire an event to tell the child when the data is back from the server:

```
var item = Vue.extend({
    props: ['items'],
  data:function(){return{items:[]}},
  template: '<div v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</div>',
  ready: function(){

    this.$on('datahere', function(){
        alert(this.items[0].id);
      //console.log('datahere items', this.items);

    })
    //console.log('items from child component', this.items);
  }
})

Vue.component('item', item);

var items = Vue.extend({
    ready: function(){
    this.init();
  },
  data: function(){
    return {
        items: {}
    }
  },
  methods:{
    init: function(){
        this.getItems();

    },
    getItems: function(){
        this.$http.get('https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos')
        .success(function(data){
          this.$set('items', data);
          this.$nextTick(function(){
                this.$broadcast('datahere', data);
          });

          console.log('items from parent components: ', this.$get('items'));
        })
    }
  },
    template: '<div class="test"><item :items.sync="items"></item></test>',
  components: {'item': item}
})

Vue.component('items', items);



var app =  new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

Comment: That's indeed the problem. I've tried to modify my fiddle with your idea, but it doesnt work. https://jsfiddle.net/kmrfkynf/5/ The object is still empty

Comment: I added `nextTick()` and also initialized the `items` array.  It looks to be working now with my changes above.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Douglas.Sesar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1402488/douglas-sesar) said, the `ready` method on the `item` component fires before the results come back from the server.

To fix that, all you need to add is the [`activate hook`](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#activate-Hook):

```
var item = Vue.extend({

  activate: function(done) {
    var unwatch = this.$watch('items', function() {
      unwatch(); // teardown the watcher
      done(); // ready to insert the component
    });
  },

  props: ['items'],
  template: '<div v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</div>',
  ready: function(){
    console.log('items from child component', this.items);
  }
})
```

That hook is called before component insertion. The component will not be inserted until the `done` callback is called. The `done` callback is called when the `items` changed (see [`watch`](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-watch) for details). Hence, the `items` will have the correct data when the `ready` function is called.

https://jsfiddle.net/kmrfkynf/8/

Comment: Thats a really nice solutions aswell. Thanks for pointing that out. Might be better then having to make a watcher for every api i call